# Pandas .corr() returning "__"

Tags: pandas, seaborn, heatmap, correlation

It was working great until it wasn't, and no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've reduced it to a very simple datsaset t:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   3   16  3   2   17  2   3   2
1   3   16  3   2   19  4   3   2
2   3   16  3   2   9   2   3   2
3   3   16  3   2   19  1   3   2
4   3   16  3   2   17  2   3   1
5   3   16  3   2   17  1   17  1
6   3   16  3   2   19  1   17  2
7   3   16  3   2   19  4   3   1
8   3   16  3   2   19  1   3   2
9   3   16  3   2   7   2   17  1




corr = t.corr()
corr
```

returns "__"

and

sns.heatmap(corr)

throws the following error "zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity"

I have no idea what's wrong? I've tried it with more rows etc, and double checked that I don't have nay missing values...what's going on? I had such a pretty heatmap earlier, I've been trying to

Comment: Work on my side ..

Comment: I´ve tried what you have in your code and returned a matrix where the first four columns appear a NaN result, it must be because this columns have a constant value and from thedefault correlation metric in this pd.corr method is pearson's formula, that implies a covariance between two variables and divided to their respective variances. And because the variance of a constant value is zero, you must see what's wrong with this dataset you have

Comment: It just happened to have the same values for the first few rows, I expanded it to make sure they have different values and still have the same issue. What's weird is you are saying you actually got a matrix with Nans and another guy is saying he got it to fully work. But min returns an empty data frame. I started a new session completely to make sure there wasn't something else going on, but still jsut get an empty dataframe back

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above, change type to float. Simply,

```
corr = t.astype('float64').corr()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not the dataframe itself but the origin of it. I found same problem by using drop or iloc in a dataframe. The key is the global type the dataframe has.
Let's say we have the following dataframe:

```
list_ex = [[1.1,2.1,3.1,4,5,6,7,8],[1.2,2.2,3.3,4.1,5.5,6,7,8], 
[1.3,2.3,3,4,5,6.2,7,8],[1.4,2.4,3,4,5,6.2,7.3,8.1]]
list_ex_new=pd.DataFrame(list_ex)
```

you can calculate the list_ex_new.corr() with no problem. If you check the arguments of the dataframe by vars(list_ex_new), you'll obtain:

```
{'_is_copy': None, '_data': BlockManager
 Items: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)
 Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)
 FloatBlock: slice(0, 8, 1), 8 x 4, dtype: float64, '_item_cache': {}}
```

where dtype is float64.

A new dataframe can be defined by list_new_new = list_ex_new.iloc[1:,:] and the correlations can be evaluated, successfully. A check of the dataframe's attributes shows:
     {'_is_copy': ,
     '_data': BlockManager
     Items: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)
     Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=1, stop=4, step=1)
     FloatBlock: slice(0, 8, 1), 8 x 3, dtype: float64,
     '_item_cache': {}}

where dtype is still float64.

A third dataframe can be defined:

```
list_ex_w = [['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a'],[1.1,2.1,3.1,4,5,6,7,8], 
[1.2,2.2,3.3,4.1,5.5,6,7,8],[1.3,2.3,3,4,5,6.2,7,8], 
[1.4,2.4,3,4,5,6.2,7.3,8.1]]
list_ex_new_w=pd.DataFrame(list_ex_w)
```

A evaluation of dataframe's correlation will result in a empty dataframe, since list_ex_w attributes look like:

```
 {'_is_copy': None, '_data': BlockManager
 Items: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)
 Axis 1: Index(['a', 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='object')
 ObjectBlock: slice(0, 8, 1), 8 x 5, dtype: object, '_item_cache': {}}
```

Where now dtype is 'object', since the dataframe is not consistent in its types. there are strings and floats together. Finally, a fourth dataframe can be generated:

```
 list_new_new_w = list_ex_new_w.iloc[1:,:]
```

this will generate as a result same notebook but with no 'a's, apparently a perfectly correct dataframe to calculate the correlations. However this will return again an empty dataframe. A final check of the dataframe attributes shows:

```
vars(list_new_new_w)

{'_is_copy': None, '_data': BlockManager
 Items: Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='object')
 Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)
 ObjectBlock: slice(0, 4, 1), 4 x 8, dtype: object, '_item_cache': {}}
```

where dtype is still object, thus the method corr returns an empty dataframe.
This problem can be solved by using astype(float)

```
 list_new_new_w.astype(float).corr()
```

In summary, it seems pandas at the time corr or cov among others methods are called generate a new dataframe with same attibutes ignoring the case the new dataframe has a consistent global type. I've been checking out the pandas source code and I understand this is the correct interpretation of pandas' implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you see "__" when you call the `.corr()` method on a Pandas DataFrame, the correlation coefficient between two columns is undefined. Basically, the correlation matrix couldn't be calculated because there are some missing or undefined data in your DataFrame.

To fix this, you must deal with the NaN (Not a Number) values in your DataFrame. You have a few options here, but one common way is to fill the NaN values with a specific value using the `.fillna()` method.

For example, let's say you have a DataFrame called `df` with some NaN values in it

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'B': [2, 4, None, 8, 10],
    'C': [3, 6, 9, None, 15]
})
```

To fill the NaN values with the mean of the column, you can use `df.fillna(df.mean())`

```
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

This will replace every NaN value with the mean value of the corresponding column. With the NaN values filled in, you should be able to call `.corr()` without getting any "__" values.

If you're still seeing "__" values after filling NaN values, it might be because the standard deviation of one or both of the columns is zero. In that case, you could try dropping rows or columns with NaN values using the `.dropna()` method.